# Magento ver. 1.9.1.1 There has been an error processing your request, but only on one area

Tags: error, cache, security, exception, magento-1.9.1.1

I am new to Magento and not very technical so apologies. The majority of the website seems to be working well, but on one specific product it keeps bringing up the warning `"There has been an error processing your request. Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons"`. I have tried various suggestions from the forums, but don't have an errors or **var/report** on my system. Please can someone provide step by step instructions as to how to fix this, as it is one of my more popular products.

Comment: On your server there will be a var/reports directory. Look for the report number that was shown on the page when the error occurred and post its contents here

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have errors in the `var/report` directory, try to enable error displaying temporarily. Go to the `error` folder in the Magento installation directory and duplicate the `local.xml.sample` file with name `local.xml`. In that way you will have the error details directly in your browser. If you are doing that on the production environment, do not forget to remove the `local.xml` after debugging.